# Generic Search Functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement in which a search functionality will need to be implemented with the following features.

1. Search functionality should be applicable to any View that is generic.
2. The view on which it is implemented in has to be for that view so its entities should be populated on the search dropdownlist (for example for the Product controller product attributes should be populated and theUser view userid, username as dropdownlist)
3. It will have Logical operators as Greater than, Less than, equal to etc with a text box to match a text entered by user.

Please let me know any link or article from i can refer to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a implementation in Asp.net MVC this is a nice blog about it:
http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2012/2/18/aspnet-mvc-generic-filtering-based-on-expressions